# How to make a GameObject upside down through code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a rocket in Unity that goes up and after 5 seconds lands. However, it lands like this:

[image: Rocket.]

I have to make it land upside down. How can I make this through code?

My current code as it is:

```
double t = 5.0;

void Update () {
GameObject Paraquedas;
GameObject CorpoNariz;
CorpoNariz = GameObject.Find("Corpo_Nariz");
Paraquedas = GameObject.Find("Paraquedas");
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 15);
        t -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (t <= 0) {
        Destroy (CorpoNariz);
        Paraquedas.renderer.enabled = true;
        transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        rigidbody.AddForce(-transform.up * 50);
        rigidbody.drag = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the script reference for transform.Rotate of Unity
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Try version 3 of Rotate functions. See the given example here:

`void Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the scale Y from 1 to -1 will do.

```
gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,-1,1);
```

[image]

[image]